# Json deserialize error AggregateException c#

Tags: json, aggregateexception

I am getting an error trying to move a DataSourceResult from one web service to another... the client calls web service A  which resides on our web server.  We then make a call to web service B which resides on our db server.  The intent is that web service A adds certain sensitive data to the call, that we want hidden behind our firewall... then the call gets handled by web service B, gets a DataSourceResult, and seems to serialize it just fine... note I am using the same set of serilization properties to bot serialize and deserialize, I am just not showing the call to serilize here for brevity.  When I go to deserialize this, I get a System.AggregateException - thrown on line  "return formatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(typeof(T), stream, null, null).Result as T;" of my deserialization code... any ideas?  anything would be much appreciated :)

Serilize code:

```
    string Serialize<T>(MediaTypeFormatter formatter, T value)
    {
        // Create a dummy HTTP Content.
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        var content = new StreamContent(stream);
        /// Serialize the object.
        formatter.WriteToStreamAsync(typeof(T), value, stream, content, null).Wait();
        // Read the serialized string.
        stream.Position = 0;
        return content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

Deserialize code:

```
    T Deserialize<T>(MediaTypeFormatter formatter, string str) where T : class
    {
        // Write the serialized string to a memory stream.
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(str);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        // Deserialize to an object of type T
        return formatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(typeof(T), stream, null, null).Result as T;
    }
```

Json Object / settings being passed into methods:

```
            var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.OfType<System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();
            json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
            json.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
            json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            json.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
            json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;

            DataSourceResult result = Deserialize<DataSourceResult>(json, loansJson);
```

I have this string I try to deserialize and it throws this 
error:

```
`System.AggregateException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
       at Cavatica35.Web.Api.Controllers.RelationshipsGridController.Deserialize[T](MediaTypeFormatter formatter, String str) in c:\dev\Cavatica35\Code\MarginMaximizerInteractive\Cavatica35.Web\Api\Controllers\RelationshipsGridController.cs:line 54
       at Cavatica35.Web.Api.Controllers.RelationshipsGridController.Get(RelationshipDataSourceRequest request) in c:\dev\Cavatica35\Code\MarginMaximizerInteractive\Cavatica35.Web\Api\Controllers\RelationshipsGridController.cs:line 96
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
       HResult=-2146233088
System.AggregateException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
       at Cavatica35.Web.Api.Controllers.RelationshipsGridController.Deserialize[T](MediaTypeFormatter formatter, String str) in c:\dev\Cavatica35\Code\MarginMaximizerInteractive\Cavatica35.Web\Api\Controllers\RelationshipsGridController.cs:line 54
       at Cavatica35.Web.Api.Controllers.RelationshipsGridController.Get(RelationshipDataSourceRequest request) in c:\dev\Cavatica35\Code\MarginMaximizerInteractive\Cavatica35.Web\Api\Controllers\RelationshipsGridController.cs:line 96
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Error converting value "{"$id":"1","Data":[{"$id":"2","Relationship_loanOfficerName":"Deva MMi Admin","guidID":"c4327c4a-7aa5-4503-b738-59a9241a5a1c","name":"New Deva","briefDescription":null,"fullDescription":"","autoRenewLOC":0,"numOfLoans":1,"loanBalance":1000000.0,"numOfDeposits":0,"Relationship_depositbalance":0.0,"numOfOtherRels":0,"otherRelBalance":0.0,"targetROE":0.0,"yearsRemaining":5,"ownedBy":"21973a46-c06e-4ddc-8a94-05bb53c949e6","modBy":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","createdBy":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","modDate":"12/18/2014","createdDate":"1/1/0001","Relationship_netincome":16955.0,"Relationship_relationshiproe":26.48,"Relationship_avgbalance":1000000.0,"monthsUntilFirstRenewal":"1/1/0001","requiresReview":false,"deleted":false,"extIDList":"","overrideOfficer":false,"selected":false,"ni":16954.908394431,"niOverROE":64028.495587965743,"tag":""}],"Total":1,"AggregateResults":[{"$id":"3","Value":1,"Member":"name","FormattedValue":1,"ItemCount":0,"Caption":null,"FunctionName":"Count_name_28477829","AggregateMethodName":"Count"},{"$id":"4","Value":16955.0,"Member":"Relationship_netincome","FormattedValue":16955.0,"ItemCount":0,"Caption":null,"FunctionName":"Sum_Relationship_netincome_244267","AggregateMethodName":"Sum"},{"$id":"5","Value":26.48,"Member":"Relationship_relationshiproe","FormattedValue":26.48,"ItemCount":0,"Caption":null,"FunctionName":"Sum_Relationship_relationshiproe_8060817","AggregateMethodName":"Sum"},{"$id":"6","Value":1000000.0,"Member":"Relationship_avgbalance","FormattedValue":1000000.0,"ItemCount":0,"Caption":null,"FunctionName":"Sum_Relationship_avgbalance_64680392","AggregateMethodName":"Sum"},{"$id":"7","Value":1,"Member":"numOfLoans","FormattedValue":1,"ItemCount":0,"Caption":null,"FunctionName":"Sum_numOfLoans_54078176","AggregateMethodName":"Sum"},{"$id":"8","Value":1000000.0,"Member":"loanBalance","FormattedValue":1000000.0,"ItemCount":0,"Caption":null,"FunctionName":"Sum_loanBalance_39749352","AggregateMethodName":"Sum"},{"$id":"9","Value":0,"Member":"numOfDeposits","FormattedValue":0,"ItemCount":0,"Caption":null,"FunctionName":"Sum_numOfDeposits_36660208","AggregateMethodName":"Sum"},{"$id":"10","Value":0.0,"Member":"Relationship_depositbalance","FormattedValue":0.0,"ItemCount":0,"Caption":null,"FunctionName":"Sum_Relationship_depositbalance_1827337","AggregateMethodName":"Sum"},{"$id":"11","Value":16954.908394431,"Member":"ni","FormattedValue":16954.908394431,"ItemCount":0,"Caption":null,"FunctionName":"Sum_ni_60302147","AggregateMethodName":"Sum"},{"$id":"12","Value":64028.495587965743,"Member":"niOverROE","FormattedValue":64028.495587965743,"ItemCount":0,"Caption":null,"FunctionName":"Sum_niOverROE_43813805","AggregateMethodName":"Sum"}],"Errors":null}" to type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceResult'. Path '', line 1, position 3087.
       Source=Newtonsoft.Json
       StackTrace:
            at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
            at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
            at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
            at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
            at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
            at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
            at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
            at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
            at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
       InnerException: System.ArgumentException
            HResult=-2147024809
            Message=Could not cast or convert from System.String to Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceResult.
            Source=Newtonsoft.Json
            StackTrace:
                 at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType)
                 at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
                 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
            InnerException: `
```

Comment: Interestingly I get the same error if I try to deserilize the object right after serializing it...
                DataSourceResult result = results.ToDataSourceResult(requestKendo);



                string s = Serialize<DataSourceResult>(json, result);
                DataSourceResult t = Deserialize<DataSourceResult>(json, s);